# Discord follow for non-announcement (regular) channels

Tags: discord

Is there a bot or a piece of code that would make it possible for posts from one channel (non admin) to be posted to another channel (admin)?
Almost exact like current FOLLOW function on announcements channel in certain groups.

To make it even more simple, a function that would forward messages from channels (non admin group) to a channel(s) in another group (admin).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a discord bot for that.
There are a lot of discord bot frameworks(discord.js, Eris, discord.py, Discordgo, etc.) but I know only discord.py so I'll write a little bot with discord.py down below /

```py
import discord
client = discord.Client()
channel1id = idOfTheChannelYouWantToFollow
channel2id = idOfTheChannelYouWantToForward

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == channel1id:
        channeltosend = client.get_channel(channel2id)
        await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0])

client.run("TOKEN")
```

I suppose you don't that much programming so I will explain how to use this code.
First, you should create a bot account by Discord developer portal. You can watch this video between 2:20 and 3:30: https://youtu.be/rAMtjPTcyc8
Then you should have Python installed on your computer. If you get an error when you write `py --version` on your cmd or when you write `python3 --version` on your terminal, go to python.org and install the latest python version and setup.

Then write this on cmd(if you are on windows): `py -3 -m pip install discord.py`
Or write this on your terminal(if you are on mac/linux): `python3 -m pip install discord.py`

So if you downloaded python and installed discord.py using pip, create a file with .py extension.
Write the code I've write above. But change the parts `idOfTheChannelYouWantToFollow` and `idOfTheChannelYouWantToForward` with the channels' IDs.
You can get a channel's ID by right-clicking to that channel on sidebar and click "Copy ID" on discord. If you can't see "Copy ID" when you right-click on a channel at sidebar, then activate developer mode on Discord at Settings>Advanced.
And change the TOKEN with your bot's token. You can get it by Discord Dev. portal.
If your code is ready, save your .py file and run it using your cmd/terminal.
You can learn how to run a python file using cmd/terminal by googling. It is pretty simple.

If you didn't understand or got stuck, you can watch videos about writing Discord bots using discord.py on youtube or you can google your problem.

Good Luck!