# Discord: Reading messages from one channel in a (non-admin perm) server, and posting it to another (with admin perms)

Tags: discord, hosting

I am new to Discord API framework.

`ServerFROM` is a public server that I was invited to (non-admin perms). Hence I cannot add bots there. But I can view the content in `ChannelFROM` (a text channel in `ServerFROM`)

I have my own `ServerTO` (in which I have admin perms and so can do anything). Inside of which, I have the target `ChannelTO`

I want to deploy a listener on `ChannelFROM`, such when there is a new message (announcement) in `ChannelFROM`, I want it to be read and reposted in `ChannelTO`.
Something similar to what is done in [this Stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67033009/discord-follow-for-non-announcement-regular-channels), except that I cannot have some script run locally 24x7 on my machine. Maybe use Github Actions or something similar?

How can I go about doing it? Any ideas are appreciated. Maybe some form of a server, or just a custom Discord bot
And thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `ChannelFROM` is an `announcement` channel, you can simply use the `Follow` option to have its messages posted to `ChannelTO`. If not, you only option is to have a bot added to `ServerFROM` that with transfer messages for you. However, Discord intends to restrict bots simply reading messages like this by April 2022, meaning if you do go that route, it will only be viable until that time.

Comment: I don't think it's an announcement channel (although the name says it)
Also are you sure that that would if ChannelTO is in a diiferent server than ChannelFROM?

Comment: Consider asking the server owner to make the channel an announcement channel (if that is what it is being used for)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Custom bot for that. I dont know other way

here's how i do it

1st : We Get the ID of the Channel that you wanted to listen
2nd : We make a Output or where the bot copy the message from and send it
3rd : Bot required a permission to view the channel and send message

or in the nutshell ( sorry if im bad at explaining )

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
if(message.author.bot) return;

if(message.channel.id === ID_HERE) // ChannelFROM in ID_HERE
{
  let MSG = message.content
  let Author = message.member.displayName

  let Avatar = message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})
  
  const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(Author , Avatar )
  .setDescription(MSG)
  .setColor("RANDOM")
  
  
  client.channels.cache.get(ID_HERE).send({ embeds: [Embed] }) // SendTo in ID_HERE
   
}
})
```

you can remove `if(message.author.bot) return;` if you want it also read other bot message on that specific channel

Comment: But the bot that is running this, is only on ServerTO, not ServerFROM. So can it really be able to read a message from ServerFROM (the  `client.on("messageCreate", message => ...` part)?

Comment: well thats the problem using custom bot, im not sure how to make it read the ServeFrom channel if the bot isnt in the ServerFrom.

Comment: A bot can't access messages from a server it does not belong to @TempoRary